# Find a point on a line that creates a perpendicular in 3D space

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

[image: Visual of Question]

Given the values of points A, B, and C, find the value of point D, where line BD is perpendicular to line AC.

This isn't homework, I'm creating a gizmo representation of "Spherecast" in unity.
I know this is probably a pretty easy problem, I'm just really rusty with trig and can't find the right words in google.

Comment: Perhaps you will benefit from looking at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62633/orthogonal-projection-of-a-point-onto-a-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since point $D$ will be on $AC$, then there exists a scalar $t \in \mathbb{R} $ such that

$ D = A + t (C - A) \hspace{20pt}(1)$

The vector $(C-A)$ is the direction vector of the ray $AC$.  Now we want want $BD = D - B $ to be perpendicular to $(C - A)$.  Then using dot product we must have

$ [(A - B) + t (C - A)] \cdot (C - A) = 0 \hspace{20pt} (2) $

From which, $ t = \dfrac{ (B - A) \cdot (C - A) }{ (C - A) \cdot (C - A) } \hspace{20pt}(3) $

Using $t$ from $(3)$ into $(1)$ gives the point $D$.